# count length of international domain name throw SQL (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, idn

I have several domain names saved in database in idn format ("xn--"). I want to run some statistics queries, but have problem to count characters on these domain names

```
SELECT
    dom_name,
    char_length(dom_name) as raw_length, -- counted with zone extension for now
FROM
    my_domains_table;
```

Ofcourse i have mistake about "xn--" domains, and i wanted to get count from sql (not using php further or some other language).

Or, please, give me some advice how to do it better.

-
In first save domain names into table in UTF-8 would be great, but this is not an option right now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can install *untrusted* languages to your database, like `PL/PerlU` or `PL/PythonU`, then you can create `punycode_decode` function using `Net::IDN::Encode` perl module or `decode('idna')` python string class member function.

If you don't, then you'd need to implement it using pl/pgsql, which won't be easy.